# Convert decimal range to Numpy array, with each bit being an array element

Tags: python, numpy

I have created a small function that takes as input an integer, `length`, and returns a `numpy` `array` of the binary representation of all `2**length` integer numbers in the range `[0:2**length-1]`.

```
import numpy as np

def get_bitstrings(length):
  # We need to binary-fy 2^length numbers.
  iterations = 2**length
  # Pre-allocate memory.
  the_array = np.zeros((iterations, length))
  # Go through all decimals in the range [0:iterations-1]
  for num in range(iterations):
    # Get binary representation in string format with 'length' zeroes padded
    t_string = '{f_num:0{f_width}b}'.format(f_num=num, f_width=length)
    # Convert to a Python list
    t_list   = list(t_string)
    # Convert to Numpy array and store.
    the_array[num,:] = np.array(t_list)

  return the_array

if __name__ == '__main__':
  var1 = get_bitstrings(2)
  var2 = get_bitstrings(3)
  print('var1:\n{}\n'.format(var1))
  print('var2:\n{}\n'.format(var2))
```

which yields:

```
var1:
[[ 0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.]]

var2:
[[ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.]]
```

The process includes getting a binary representation of each integer number as a string (with 0s padded before it such that the length is constant at `length`), converting the string into a Python list, and then converting the list into a `numpy` `array`.

I found that to be the only way to satisfy the requirement that each bit is an entry in the array – i.e., bitstring `1010` is a `1x4` `numpy` `array` and not simply an integer in a `1x1` array. But I am sure there are better alternatives, hence the question.

The problem, as you can imagine, is that this is inefficient. I was wondering whether I can improve this by using Python/Numpy trickery.

*Edit*:
I used to do this in MATLAB with this snippet:

> t_length = 5;
>   dc = [0:2^t_length-1]';
>   bc = rem(floor(dc*pow2(-(t_length-1):0)),2);

But I am a complete noob when it comes to Python/Numpy! Maybe it'll inspire someone. `:-)`

Comment: Possibly you could work something out with strides but I think even bools are represented as 8 bits in numpy...

Comment: `np.arange(2 ** k)` will give an actual "bitstring" (i.e. `np.int`) with the required binary value. What do you need this for?

Comment: @deinonychusaur I need the elements to be integers or floatz, not booleans.

Comment: @Iarsmans I am not sure what you mean. I need the binary representation of decimal numbers in this specific format because I'm doing linear algebra with bit-strings -- it has to do with evolutionary computation.

Comment: Have a look at `numpy.binary_repr`. E.g. `[np.binary_repr(item, width=5) for item in range(2**5)]`.  This will give you strings, but you can convert to an array of ints quite easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use NumPy's broadcasting and vectorized operations to do this fairly efficiently:

```
>>> from numpy import arange, newaxis
>>> powers_of_two = 2**arange(4)[::-1]
>>> (arange(2**4)[:, newaxis] & powers_of_two) / powers_of_two
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

Brief explanation:  we're taking all the integers from 0 to 15 (`arange(2**4)`), then reshaping that to given an array of shape `(16, 1)` (that's the `[:, newaxis]` slice part).  Then we take the bitwise-and with powers of two, from highest to lowest (`2**arange(4)[::-1]`).  The reshaping ensures that the bitwise and operation is performed as a sort of 'outer' operation: we take the bitwise and of every element of the original `arange` with every element of the `powers_of_two` array.  This is NumPy's [broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) and [slicing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing) at work.  The absence of an explicit Python-level `for` loop should make this significantly faster than a solution based on `for` loops or list comprehensions.

Here's a somewhat sleeker, and as it turns out, faster, alternative along the same lines:

```
>>> from numpy import arange, newaxis
>>> arange(2**4)[:,newaxis] >> arange(4)[::-1] & 1
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

As always, if efficiency is a concern then you should make good use of the tools that Python provides in the form of the [timeit](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/timeit.html) and [profile](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/profile.html) modules.  Timings on my machine with `length=16` seem to indicate that the second variant is significantly faster than the first:

```
taniyama:~ mdickinson$ python -m timeit -s "from numpy import arange, newaxis" "arange(1<<16)[:, newaxis] >> arange(16)[::-1] & 1"
100 loops, best of 3: 4.08 msec per loop
taniyama:~ mdickinson$ python -m timeit -s "from numpy import arange, newaxis" "(arange(1<<16)[:, newaxis] & 2**arange(16)[::-1]) / 2**arange(16)[::-1]"
10 loops, best of 3: 21.6 msec per loop
```

Comment: Wow! This is incredibly fast and elegant. Thanks a lot, Mark!

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use `numpy.binary_repr`. It will result in a string, but you can easily convert that to an array of ints or floats (just change the `dtype` argument).  For example:

```
import numpy as np

k = 4
print np.array([list(np.binary_repr(x, k)) for x in range(2**k)], dtype=int)
```

This yields:

```
[[0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 1 1]
 [0 1 0 0]
 [0 1 0 1]
 [0 1 1 0]
 [0 1 1 1]
 [1 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 1]
 [1 0 1 0]
 [1 0 1 1]
 [1 1 0 0]
 [1 1 0 1]
 [1 1 1 0]
 [1 1 1 1]]
```

Or, if you wanted a more readable version:

```
def bitstrings(k):
    binary = [np.binary_repr(item, width=k) for item in range(2**k)]
    return np.array([list(item) for item in binary], dtype=int)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, Joe, but I would rather avoid a purely iterated solution because that is what I was doing in the first place. Mark's answer comes closer to what I was asking.

Comment: Yeah, Mark's answer is quite slick!